# Assignment to a constructor? (like a tuple-tier)

Tags: c++, constructor, assignment-operator

Why can't I assign to a constructor, when I can assign to a function that "looks" like a constructor?

Example:

```
struct Bar {
   Bar() : b_(false) {}
   Bar(bool b) : b_(b) {}
};

struct Foo {
   Foo(Bar const & bar) : bar_(bar) {}
   Foo operator=(Foo const & f) { return Foo(f.bar_); }
   const Bar & bar_;
}

Foo bool_to_foo(bool b) { return Foo(Bar(b)); }

Foo MakeFoo(Bar const & bar) { return Foo(bar); }
```

Why does this work:

```
Bar bar;
MakeFoo(bar) = bool_to_foo(true);
```

when this doesn't work?

```
Bar bar;
Foo(bar) = bool_to_foo(true);  // Error: 'bar': redefinition; different basic types
```

MakeFoo(.) and Foo(.) have the same signature, and the same function.

What's special about the constructor?

Comment: You can never "assign to a function". You can assign to a function object, though!

Comment: Oh, and when you see `Foo()` in an expression in your code, it's _never_ "the constructor". It is impossible to _directly_ call or refer to a constructor.

Comment: You don't "assign to a function" in your code, you try to assign to the return value of a function.

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit--Take a look at boost::tuples::tie, where they use the "assign to a function" quite effectively.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line:

```
Foo(bar) = bool_to_foo(true);
```

does not do what you think it does. It does *not* declare a temporary object initialized with `bar`.
What it actually does is to declare an object named `bar` of type `Foo` and initialize it with the value `bool_to_foo(true)`.

In that sense, it is exactly equivalent to:

```
Foo bar = bool_to_foo(true);
```

Since you already have an object named `bar` in scope, this is a redefinition.

---

If you still want to do what you are trying to do, you might try:

```
Foo((0,bar)) = bool_to_foo(true);
```

But, since that is both ugly and confusing, I won't describe it further.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `s/d/D/g` :P

Comment: @Robᵩ--Very insightful. Definitely syntactic weirdness (or at least unexpected).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: true

Answer (score 0):

The `MakeFoo()` function returns an object, which can then be assigned to (though I suspect with compiler warnings on it will complain about assigning to a temporary).  However, as you have surmised, the C++ standard gives constructors special treatment.  Though I am not completely sure, I suspect that the `= bool_to_foo(true)` part is treated as an initialization, not as an assignment.  This would cause an error, as foo has no copy constructor.

Rob also hit the nail on the head with the Foo(bar) deal.  C++ syntax can be strange sometimes.

In any case, either of these forms is bad practice - assigning to rvalues is *probably* not what you want and will most likely confuse people if it is.

Comment: @Robert--"bad practice" in C++ seems to be SOP in Haskell...they seem to assign to type constructors all the time.  Just trying to branch out to the FP world a bit!

Comment: @DavidH: Haskell is awesome.  But style/practice doesn't port across languages.  In C++ this syntax means something completely different from its usage in Haskell.  What `MakeFoo(bar) = baz(quuz)` means in c++ is that the purposes of that expression *is* side-effects.  Quite antithetical to anything in Haskell.